# C# .net Emgu application - Works fine in Debug-Mode but not in Release-Mode

Tags: c#, .net, emgucv

I wrote a small application in C# and used the emgucv library to do some image processing.
When I start my app in debug mode everything is running fine and with no problems.

When I switch to release mode or when I publish my application I get weird image results and the images are looking completely destroyed. The app itself is running with our errors. In Debug mode the images are looking fine.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw1PM.png)

[Project LibView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjexx.png)

All libs are loaded and I'm not linking to any debugging lib. No errors messages and no exceptions. Only the weird image result.

Any ideas?

Comment: search on how to reference an external library so that is makes it into the published output

Comment: Thx for the fast answer. The libs are in published mode all loaded correctly. The result the emgu cv lib is creating is somehow wrong. The lib behaves differently when not in debug mode

Comment: Are you using PInvoke? Are you using the latest version of the library?